# why image display below when click on image in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

can you please tell me why my image display below when I click the thumb nail image.I am using lightbox plugin I study doc from here
https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/
In example it show image above the image..which css file I am missing ?
fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/xnhtg1t1/

```
<a class="example-image-link lightbox" href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/51wtwmqnnokotj6/image-1.jpg?dl=0" data-lightbox="example-1"><img class="example-image" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/w85pcbopymjzn76/thumb-1.jpg?dl=0" alt="image-1" /></a>
```

Comment: take a look to your dev tools console and enjoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the GET variable `?dl=0` from your JS and CSS urls and it works. [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/xnhtg1t1/3/)

That is Dropbox's [download parameter](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/url-tricks), while although it is set to false.. it is still causing the issue.

Comment: this doesn't do anything.

Comment: Click the demo, it runs like it should

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the resource tab.

Comment: thanks. your answer is correct how to show next and previous buttons in bigger image when there is multiple image

Comment: how to add next https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/unxg9pmk6udvgui/next.png  .previous https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1x7657iq49dag7h/prev.png.  close image https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mj88p54itcrkj0e/close.png

Comment: how to add these images in when when multiple images

Comment: You fix the references to `../prev.png` in the css. Its a relative url and means go up a folder and find the image prev.png I replaced the image urls for you. http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/xnhtg1t1/4/ Copy that css if you want to continue using dropbox as your hosting. Please mark this question correct :) and feel free to open new questions if you have any more. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Make position of the Lightbox absolute instead of relative.

```
.lightbox {
   position: absolute;
}
```

Or even FIXED. And then it will appear on top of the page. Then you can construct the lightbox styles however you like.

http://jsfiddle.net/xnhtg1t1/2/

Comment: The plugin's CSS provides the positioning already, there are console errors.